# Is "Dera Sacha Sauda" part of Hinduism or a different religion?

Tags: other-religions, guru

Recently after the conviction of [Gurmeet Ram Rahim Singh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gurmeet_Ram_Rahim_Singh), I was wondering if the [Dera Sacha Sauda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dera_Sacha_Sauda) is merely a cult or a part of Hindu religion?
What kind of philosophy do they believe in?

Comment: Only philosophy in which they believe is, making as much money as possible by fooling people. They wanna live luxuries life and they are living that life. All the religious activities of their are just tools to fool people, nothing else. They only Believe in Moneyism, not in Hinduism.

Comment: Don't know why so much up votes on an off-topic question. This is not `DeraSachaSauda.stackexchange.com`, But instead it is `hinduism.stackexchange.com`. OP is not asking question about Hinduism but instead he is asking question about an organisation. This is not dera site in which such question should be asked.

Comment: @Rishabh, The Qn intends to know whether such a sect is part of "Hindu religion" or not. There are many sects in Hinduism and we don't have separate stackexchanges for each of them. All the Qn related to them are asked here. If you visit the wiki article, the DSS appears with Hindu symbols & they have their own followers. There are many godmen convictions in recent time. But may be they are not related to Hinduism, as [wrongly] projected by media. If in future, someone searches DSS with respect to Hinduism then there is a likelihood of this thread popping up.

Comment: But you are asking question about an organisation. You want to know about believes of an organisation which has nothing to do with this sites IMO. Your question is directly related to an organisation, not related to hinduism. But I might be wrong. Let other decide :)

Comment: And besides **But may be they are not related to Hinduism**. They just using name of religion. Since their purpose is just to earn, so they will choose those religion which has max no. of people so that they can earn more. They will try to fool with the name of those religion by which they can get max followers. So if they are saying hinduism then that doesn't mean they believe in this religion but they believe that this religion can give them maximum followers since max percentage of India is Hindu.

Comment: i dont think that asking if it is part of Hinduism is off-topic.

Comment: I agree with @user13107, asking if a sect is part of Hinduism or not is on-topic, so I'm reopening your question.

Answer (score 1):

The deras follow the path of Bhakti and cater to the religious needs of the Sikh and Hindu Dalits. Sikh orthodoxy considers Deras run by Sikhs as apostates. There have been attempts to kill some of the Dera chiefs by Sikh fanatics. Muslims are not part of the Deras. There is a great deal of casteism in the Punjab.Christian missionaries have converted about 1 million Sikhs in the last 30 years. Since the Sikh Dalit population and to some extent the Hindu Dalit population do not get respect in society they are either veering towards conversion to Christianity or they are joining the Deras where they are treated with respect. At least that is the opinion of some people.

https://swarajyamag.com/politics/why-people-are-willing-to-die-for-gurmeet-ram-rahim-singh-

**Are they part of Hinduism?**

They claim to be the confluence of all religions. So the answer to the above question is both yes or no. A Hindu follower can take it as part of Hinduism while a Sikh follower can think it as a Sikh organization. 
https://www.derasachasauda.org/

Comment: what is your answer to OP's question? Yes or No?

Comment: Both yes or no. It is up to the follower of Dera.